# How to reduce the size of the rectangular boxes on face detection in a group photo?

Tags: python, face-recognition, face-detection

```py
import cv2
import face_recognition as fc

image = fc.load_image_file('classA.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

face_locations = fc.face_locations(image)

print(face_locations)

for i in range(len(face_locations)):
    image = cv2.rectangle(image, (face_locations[i][3],face_locations[i][0],face_locations[i][1],face_locations[i][2]),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow(' Students present in class detected',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I was expecting detected face should have one rectangle box only of the face not whole body

Comment: What is the face recognition? A library, your custom package? Even the imshow description says "students detected" and not "faces"...Do you know what are you trying to do in detail?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need a top left corner and a bottom right corner. Like:

```
top_left = (face_locations[i][3], face_locations[i][0])
bottom_right = (face_locations[i][1], face_locations[i][2])
image = cv2.rectangle(image, top_left, bottom_right, (0,255,0), 2)
```

Hope it works for you.